# PostgreSQL Idle Session in Transactions with RELEASE_EXEC_SVP queries and lock

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am having a problem with having idle sessions in transactions. In pgAdmin Server Status, it is showing "RELEASE_EXEC_SVP_XXXXXX" (XXXXXX data are varied) as its query and it's locks also contain a lot of these "RELEASE_EXEC_SVP_XXXXXX" entries. What do these mean? These commonly cause lock blocking problems because these sessions sometimes lock other rows but the session is always idle in transaction. I do not know why there are sessions like these.

Version of PostgreSQL is 9.2.8 running on Windows using psqlodbc 9.03.0210.

Comment: I have reviewed our system and do not see any possibility of transactions getting started that are not rollbacked or committed so this must be something internal to postgresql.